# Need to get the Rect of the HTMLElement under a POINT

Tags: html

My main intention here is to make a tool like Spy++ which highlights a rectangle for any HTMLElement. Spy++ can highlight for the objects which are window objects and not HTMLElement.
I am able to find out the exact POINT using GetCursorPos() method. Do we have anything which can get me the HTMLElement rectangle under the point or even HTMLElement ?

Answer (score 0):

```
.element:hover
{
   border:1px solid black;
}
```

Add this html

```
<div class="element">Rectangle</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Abhijit but here i am trying to build a tool using C++ and trying to get the element based on the mouse position. I cannot change anything on the web page.